# Set jQuery cookie with auto-submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to use jQuery cookie to set languages.
I have the following form:

```
<select id="lang">
    <option value="en_US">English</option>
    <option value="it_IT">Italiano</option>
    <option value="fr_FR">Français</option>
</select>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="submit">
<noscript><input id="btn" type="button" value="submit"></noscript>
```

Within the following script:

```
// Set cookie
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").on("click", function () {
        $.cookie('lang_cookie', $("#lang").val(), { expires: 365 });
    });
});
```

The form above works nicely but I'd like to remove the button and auto-submit.
I can change the form using `onchange="this.form.submit()"`:

```
<select id="lang" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="en_US">English</option>
    <option value="it_IT">Italian</option>
</select>
```

But what about the jQuery part? How can I set cookies without using `$("#btn").on("click", function (){})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the onchange event without submitting the form as below,

```
<select id="lang" onchange="set()">
    <option value="en_US">English</option>
    <option value="it_IT">Italian</option>
</select>
```

Now you can write your script as,

```
function set(){
    $.cookie('lang_cookie', $("#lang").val(), { expires: 365 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html

```
  <select id="lang" onchange="return setC(this);">
   <option value="en_US">English</option>
   <option value="it_IT">Italiano</option>
   <option value="fr_FR">Français</option>
</select>
```

Your script

```
 function setC(elem)
   {
     $.cookie(...);
      elem.form.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cookie and then submit the form:

```
// Set cookie then submit
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").on("click", function() {
        $.cookie('lang_cookie', $("#lang").val(), { expires: 365 });
        $("#btn").closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Using jQuery [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery submit doc](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
// Set cookie
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("THE ID OF YOUR FORM").submit(function () {
        $.cookie('lang_cookie', $("#lang").val(), { expires: 365 });
    });
});
```